# Debugging PHP Mail with phpmailer and XAMPP to Yahoo email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, yahoo-mail

I've downloaded the latest update of XAMPP which pretty much messed up my old config. I was at one point able to send basic mail() with PHP but once I updated it stopped.

I researched a bit and everyone recommended Zend or PHPMailer. I tried PHPMailer, it returned me an error saying cound not get a response.

Messed around with my php.ini and increased the socket timeout from 60 to 120. That didn't work so I tried sending test mails to myself.

```
Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25,
verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

So, I checked php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25;

;Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will 
;include uid of the script followed by the filename
```

Ok, so I thought, "I'll just use the PHPMailer to include the SMTP and Port:

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer();        // defaults to using php "mail()";

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP();                            // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->AddReplyTo("noreply@randomcompany.com","Company Name Here");
$mail->Host       = "localhost";           // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                      // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
$mail->Port       = 25;                     // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server


$mail->From       = "noreply@randomcompany.com";
$mail->FromName   = "Company Name Here";

$address = "test@yahoo.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "Hello to myself for testing!");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}

mail.add_x_header = Off
```

Which said:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: 
A connection attempt failed because the connected 
party did not properly respond after a period of 
time, or established connection failed because 
connected host has failed to respond. (10060)

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. 
Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Mercury Said:

```
This message is sending now ...

Error! The message was not successfully sent!

Zurück zum Formular
```

Spent all that time and I'm wondering now, is it my code, php.ini, the phpmailer, or Yahoo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing a mailserver. Or have you a local mailserver running at port 25? ;-) But XAMPP brings a mailserver with it named `Mercury` - so... start it and have fun ;-).

Comment: You reminded me, so I started it up, but I'm still getting the same errors :(

Comment: That you're not able to connect? Check your firewall settings. Try to temporarily disable it and retry executing the script.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using McAfee, doesn't look like it will let me shut it down. I did create a rule for Port 25 and gave full internet privileges to Apache. But, still unable to send mail.

Comment: full "outbound" privileges are needed for `Mercury`. The PHPMailer makes a request to `Mercury` which connects to the mailserver returned in the MX records of the domain (= most of the Internet ;)).

Comment: THANK YOu! I would have never guessed at adding Mercury.exe to the firewall privileges!